# Watch for MongoDB Change Streams

Tags: mongodb, go, event-handling, mgo, mongo-go

We want our Go application to listen to the data changes on a collection. So, googling in search for a solution, we came across MongoDB's [Change Streams](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.6/changeStreams/). That link also exhibits some implementation snippets for a bunch of languages such as Python, Java, Nodejs etc. Yet, there is no piece of code for Go.

We are using [Mgo](https://godoc.org/labix.org/v2/mgo) as a driver but could not find explicit statements on *change streams*.

Does anyone have any idea on how to watch on Change Streams using that Mgo or any other Mongo driver for Go?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The popular `mgo` driver ([`github.com/go-mgo/mgo`](https://github.com/go-mgo/mgo)) developed by Gustavo Niemeyer has gone dark (unmaintained). And it has no support for change streams.

The community supported fork [`github.com/globalsign/mgo`](https://github.com/globalsign/mgo) is in much better shape, and has already added support for change streams (see [details here](https://github.com/globalsign/mgo/pull/97)).

To watch changes of a collection, simply use the [`Collection.Watch()`](https://godoc.org/github.com/globalsign/mgo#Collection.Watch) method which returns you a value of [`mgo.ChangeStream`](https://godoc.org/github.com/globalsign/mgo#ChangeStream). Here's a simple example using it:

```
coll := ... // Obtain collection

pipeline := []bson.M{}

changeStream := coll.Watch(pipeline, mgo.ChangeStreamOptions{})
var changeDoc bson.M
for changeStream.Next(&changeDoc) {
    fmt.Printf("Change: %v\n", changeDoc)
}

if err := changeStream.Close(); err != nil {
    return err
}
```

---

Also note that there is an **official** MongoDB Go driver under development, it was announced here: [Considering the Community Effects of Introducing an Official MongoDB Go Driver](https://engineering.mongodb.com/post/considering-the-community-effects-of-introducing-an-official-golang-mongodb-driver)

It is currently in **alpha (!!)** phase, so take this into consideration. It is available here: [`github.com/mongodb/mongo-go-driver`](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-go-driver). It also already has support for change streams, similarly via the [`Collection.Watch()`](https://godoc.org/github.com/mongodb/mongo-go-driver/mongo#Collection.Watch) method (this is a different `mongo.Collection` type, it has nothing to do with `mgo.Collection`). It returns a [`mongo.Cursor`](https://godoc.org/github.com/mongodb/mongo-go-driver/mongo#Cursor) which you may use like this:

```
var coll mongo.Collection = ... // Obtain collection

ctx := context.Background()

var pipeline interface{} // set up pipeline

cur, err := coll.Watch(ctx, pipeline)
if err != nil {
    // Handle err
    return
}
defer cur.Close(ctx)

for cur.Next(ctx) {
    elem := bson.NewDocument()
    if err := cur.Decode(elem); err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    // do something with elem....
}

if err := cur.Err(); err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
}
```

Comment: Great answer, notable suggestion. Thanks!

Comment: @icza: This might be a noob question but I came from Node.js, how to obtain collection?

Comment: @piavgh It depends on the driver. In `mgo`, use [`Database.C()`](https://godoc.org/github.com/globalsign/mgo#Database.C). In `mongo-go`, use [`Database.Collection()`](https://godoc.org/go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver/mongo#Database.Collection).

Answer (score 5):

This example uses the [The MongoDB supported driver for Go](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-go-driver) with stream pipeline (filtering only documents having field1=1 and field2=false):

```
    ctx := context.TODO()
    clientOptions := options.Client().ApplyURI(mongoURI)
    client, err := mongo.Connect(ctx, clientOptions)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    err = client.Ping(ctx, nil)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    fmt.Println("Connected!")

    collection := client.Database("test").Collection("test")

    pipeline := mongo.Pipeline{bson.D{
        {"$match",
            bson.D{
                {"fullDocument.field1", 1},
                {"fullDocument.field2", false},
            },
        },
    }}
    streamOptions := options.ChangeStream().SetFullDocument(options.UpdateLookup)

    stream, err := collection.Watch(ctx, pipeline, streamOptions)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    log.Print("waiting for changes")
    var changeDoc map[string]interface{}
    for stream.Next(ctx) {
        if e := stream.Decode(&changeDoc); e != nil {
            log.Printf("error decoding: %s", e)
        }
        log.Printf("change: %+v", changeDoc)
    }
```

Comment: Are you using context.TODO() for documentation purposes?